# How to remove extra dots on urls using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Somehow GWMT detected extra dots on my url. I want to remove them completely.

for e.g. i want to change the following url from

http://www.example.com/my-sample-urls../

TO

http://www.example.com/my-sample-urls/

I use this codes before any condition rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\./([^/]+)(\.html?)$ /$1/$2$3 [L,R=301]
```

but that's not working.

Please advise and your help appreciated.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code rather :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)..$ /$1/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(/|$)(.*)$ /$1$2$3 [L,R=301]
```